# IE conditional code not working (using Jade)

Tags: internet-explorer, pug, conditional-formatting, mixins

I am trying to use IE conditional code in Jade, and I tried:

```
mixin ie(condition)
    | <!--[!{condition}]><!-->
    block
    | <!--<![endif]-->
+ie('if !IE')
    div...
```

and also

```
mixin ie(condition)
    | <!--[!{condition}]>
    block
    | <![endif]-->
+ie('if !IE')
    div...
```

I want to make it so that the code from `div` on is invisible in IE.
But in the first case the code is still visible in Internet Explorer, and in the second case it gets completely commented out in every browser.
I feel like I am missing something, please help me out!

Comment: Which version of IE are you targeting? Conditional comment isn't supported starting from IE 10: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/hh801214(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN. It will be ignored in IE 10 and above and in other browsers. Please don't use conditional comments if you're targeting IE 11.

Comment: Yes, I was using IE 10... thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Yu Zhou mentioned:
The problem was just that IE conditional code does not work from IE 10 and on.
I instead used a js code to detect IE up to 10 like this:

```
        function detectIE() {
            var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

            var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
            if (msie > 0) {
                return true;
            }

            var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
            if (trident > 0) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

And then added the components depending on the browser.